# How do i locate wordpress plugin directory?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a function from plugin 1(wp job manager) to plugin 2(woocommerce).

I have decided to do this by including the php file from plugin 1, however I am unable to locate the file directory. I have used:

```
 include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'wp-job-manager/includes/class-wp-job-manager-applications.php');
```

but it returns the following error:

> Warning:
>   include(/home/content/p3pnexwpnas05_data02/78/2394078/html/wp-content/themes/listify-child/wp-job-manager/includes/class-wp-job-manager-applications.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas05_data02/78/2394078/html/wp-content/themes/listify-child/functions.php
>   on line 77

Please advise me as I've been stuck on this issue for really long... Thanks!!!

Comment: First you should ask yourself why you are modifying these plugins? I don't know what you are doing, but you can probably just activate them both and build a 3rd plugin to bridge the two. If you modify either directly you won't be able to update them without losing your changes.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress setups have a constant `ABSPATH` defined (look at the bottom lines of `wp_config.php`) which points to the full and absolute path of the Wordpress setup, so in your case `echo ABSPATH;` would return `/home/content/p3pnexwpnas05_data02/78/2394078/html/`.

For most installations, appending `wp-content/plugins/` to that string would point you to your plugins directory.

However, in a Wordpress configuration one can also customize the wp-content and or plugins directory to their own preference, so building plugins on `ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/` is not recommended. Unfortunately Wordpress simply doesn't have a `get_absolute_pluginspath()` function or something available. A trick would be to fetch the plugins-URL, and remove the site-URL from it, so the remaining data is wp-content/plugins/ (or whatever the user has made of it). In code:

```
$plugins_directory = ABSPATH.str_replace(site_url()."/","",plugins_url())."/";
```

Which in your case would return:
`/home/content/p3pnexwpnas05_data02/78/2394078/html/wp-content/plugins/`

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean:

```
plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)
```

That gives you the directory path to the file that statement is in. So what that returns depends on where you run it. If you use this statement

```
include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'wp-job-manager/includes/class-wp-job-manager-applications.php');
```

in the main plugin file for wp_job_manager (probably wp_job_manager.php), then `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)` give the path of the directory that file is in (the plugin directory).

If you use it in some other file, you will need to adjust the rest of the path string accordingly.